# Caching lots of data in global.asax Application_Start, windows azure role

Tags: c#, caching, azure, global-asax, azure-web-roles

I am doing a ton of work currently in Application_Start, and it takes an hour or two to cache the 2 gigs of data into memory that make my application operate efficiently.

Using this method, the Azure web role instance(s) are not available until these processees are complete. I am inserting into the HTTPRuntime cache, so I cannot use the WebRole.cs OnStart() or Run() methods (they don't have acceess to this cache).

Can you think of alternate ways that I can get this data loaded into the cache, while also making the website available during this caching period? The website operates fine while the data is loading, just not as fast.

Thanks so much,
-Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the data in the Cache using a separate thread. i.e., create a separate thread and start caching the data using that thread.

You application should serve perfectly in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty simple, actually!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a stretch to call your approach caching, because caching is usually on demand (or lazy caching), as opposed to pre-caching where content is loaded before it is actually required.

1. You can switch from pre-caching to lazy caching
2. If you have to do pre-caching, you can keep cache in some sort of persistent storage, but close to your server. For Azure you have a choice between Table or Blob storage and SQL Azure. With persistent cache you don't load it every time your role instance updated or restarted.
3. If you can wait a little, [AppFabric Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714581.aspx) would provide you a lot of flexibility and scalability, so you don't have to maintain separate cache on each of your role instances.

Comment: Thanks, Seva. I'm using lazy caching as well, but I just want to do some pre-caching for some potentially slow reports. I'm looking forward to AppFabric caching. I'd use it now, but I don't think 256MB is large enough. Thanks for the tips though!